# Login to multiple application on same server from single login page using Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have multiple applications deployed on same server with custom Spring Security implemented on all. Now I want to create single app for login to all these applications so that User can navigate to all these applications after login once only.

Please suggest how can I achieve it. Also, let me know if my requirements are not clear.

Comment: Oauth2 and JWT is what you need.

Comment: @akuma8 I hope you have answered it by keeping in mind that all the applications are running on same server not on different servers.

Comment: Yes, since each application has its own port I consider it like a microservice architecture. So the best way to handle security is using a token base solution.